# How to install php 5.6 mysql extension on Mac OSX

Tags: php, mysql, macos, homebrew

I am trying to setup PHP 5.6 and one of the older sites that I work with needs the mysql extension which didn't install when I ran:

```
brew install php56 --with-fpm --with-mysql --with-httpd
```

It installed php56 and that's all working fine however it installed the mysqli extension but I need the mysql extension too.

Is there a way to install this extension to my current php setup?

Here is the currently installed php extensions that I have:

```
5.6 php -m
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dba
dom
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
intl
json
ldap
libxml
mbstring
mongodb
mysqli
mysqlnd
odbc
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
PDO_ODBC
pdo_sqlite
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
soap
sockets
SPL
sqlite3
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
wddx
xdebug
xml
xmlreader
xmlrpc
xmlwriter
xsl
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Xdebug
```

Just wondering, thanks!

Comment: Doesn't macOS (as they call it now) already come with PHP 5.6.30 *with* MySQL support? Mine does. Just run `/usr/bin/php -i` to confirm.

Comment: Indeed but I need the deprecated mysql client library for an old PHP 4 project, which isn't installed using homebrew

Comment: That makes no sense. PHP 5.6 won't install anything but the mysqlnd driver as far as I know. And you don't need the old MySQL client to run PHP 4 code, you might need the old MySQL client to connect to an old obsolete MySQL Server, like version 4.0 or something. It sounds like you have a project that is using multiple end-of-life software. It might be easier to port the application to current PHP and current MySQL.

Comment: Yeah in this instance, I need the old MySQL client as it is making mysql_connect() calls in multiple packages. It's a rather large codebase but upgrading is definitely the better option in this instance

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
brew reinstall php56 --with-fpm --with-libmysql --with-httpd
```

Per the homebrew installer [options](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/blob/9b7f4128df963895e888c550a400891a0ed1d287/Abstract/abstract-php.rb#L91), this installs the old `mysql` driver **instead of** the newer native driver.  I don't think there is any way to install both simultaneously as the drivers conflict.

If this is a new project you are working on, it may be worth the time to refactor your project to use the native driver.

Comment: I'm getting an error when I have the flag --with-fpm. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I ended up finding the solution using the following https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/4501

You can do the following:

```
just copy in /usr/local/lib:

libmysqlclient.a -> libmysqlclient_r.a
libmysqlclient.dylib -> libmysqlclient_r.dylib
try to install php with:
brew install php56 --with-libmysql --with-httpd --with-pear --build-from-source
```

Comment: This is the correct answer because in recent versions of Homebrew, php@5.6 does not use the `--with-libmysql` option unless you use `--build-from-source`. But, you don't need to manually copy the `libmysqlclient.*` files; installing mysql with brew is enough: `brew install mysql && brew link mysql`.